# AJAX Request in CodeIgniter Application Failing After Inactivity

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

The application I am working on is built in CodeIgniter, and the content is always loaded via ajax into the main content div.

This works without fail normally, apart from after the user has been inactive for a short while.

We haven't completely narrowed down the inactivity time required for the request to fail, but it's around 40 minutes or more of inactivity.

I've tried logging details to the console in the error callback of the AJAX request, but nothing is logged.

I'm thinking that it's related to a session expiry but I can't be sure. I know when using CodeIgniter, there are two sessions which are created automatically (PHPSESSID, and ci_session) so my instinct is that it has something to do with these, or one of them, expiring?

When the request fails the headers, preview, response and cookies tab on chrome's developer tools show nothing.

If anyone has experienced this before, or has any ideas what may be causing the problem, I'd appreciate the input.

**Edit:**

Below is the AJAX request which is experiencing the above problem.

All links within my application use this loadPage function instead of a standard redirect.

```
function loadPage(href, type, clickElem, changeHash) {
    if(ajax_loading == true) { return false; }
    ajax_loading = true;
    $('#recording_area').slideUp('slow');
    if(typeof queue_countdown !== 'undefined') { clearInterval(queue_countdown); }
    if(type == 'sidenav') {
        $('#sidenav_accordion .accordion-heading a').removeClass('on');
        $('#sidenav_accordion .accordion-inner a').removeClass('on');
        $(clickElem).parents('.accordion-group').find('.accordion-heading a').addClass('on');
        $(clickElem).addClass('on');
    } else {
        page_requested = href.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');
        if(!page_requested) { page_requested = 'dashboard'; }
        nav_elem = $('.sidenav a[href="/' + page_requested + '"]');
        if(nav_elem.html() != null) {
            nav_elem_group = nav_elem.parents().eq(2).children().first().find('a');
            if(!nav_elem_group.hasClass('on')) {
                if(!nav_elem.parents().eq(2).children().first().next().hasClass('in')) { nav_elem_group.click(); }
                $('.sidenav .on').removeClass('on');
                nav_elem.addClass('on');
                nav_elem_group.addClass('on');
            }
        }
    }
    current_ajax_request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: href,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#map-canvas').remove();
            $('.content_wrapper script').each(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('#gbox_Customers').remove();
            if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
                $('.content_wrapper').hide().html(data).show();
                $('#content_overlay').hide();
            } else {
                $('.content_wrapper').fadeOut().html(data).hide().fadeIn();
                $('#content_overlay').fadeOut();
            }
            $('.queue_loading').hide();
            console.log('success ended');
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error) {
            /*
             * The below console logs do not fire when the problem is occuring.
             */
            console.log('ERROR');
            console.log('xhr: ' + xhr);
            console.log('status: ' + status);
            console.log('error: ' + error);

            $('#map-canvas').remove();
            $.get('inc.404.php', function(data) {
                if($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
                    $('.content_wrapper').hide().html(data).show();
                } else {
                    $('.content_wrapper').fadeOut().html(data).hide().fadeIn();
                }
            });
            if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
                $('#content_overlay').hide();
            } else {
                $('#content_overlay').fadeOut();
            }
            $('.queue_loading').hide();
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            ajax_loading = false;
            set_tooltips();
        }
    });
    if(changeHash != false) {
        window.location.hash = "!" + href;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

After putting several console log's through the function, to see at which point it breaks. The problem decided to disappear. For what reason would adding console logs to the function prevent this issue from occurring?

I'm currently waiting an hour or so to re-test it without the console logs to make sure it isn't a red herring.

**Edit 3:**

After putting in console logs in the error callback of the AJAX request, it seems that the error callback is not firing. Not quite sure where to look now - as if it was a success, it would surely return the content.

Comment: How are your requests tied to sessions? Could you show the relevant code?

Comment: Well the request is loading pages within the application which use the sessions I referred to. Am I correct in thinking that an AJAX request won't return the data on a session timeout, where-as a browser refresh will? It's just a standard jQuery AJAX call, however I'll post the code.

Comment: @DamienPirsy see my edit to post for the function in question.

Comment: I've had the same issue before, This is fixed in the development branch of CodeIgniter (CI 3), You can get it from github or just copy the session library from there.

Comment: @ahmad I've actually changed the session library recently (unsure which version I changed it to) due to an issue where the header for created sessions was re-sent each time a new element was added to the session. This resulted in several users reporting errors due to an abnormally large header size. However the problem I'm experiencing was happening before I changed the session library also. Due to this I'm not sure we can just change the session library to the CI3 version in case the header size issue arises again. Do you know what changes fixed this issue in the CI3 session library at all?

Comment: See @Seain Malkin answer, I guess it's close to what was changed in CI 3

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what's causing your problem. But just in case this helps, here is a solution to a ajax and CI session problem I had.

Ajax requests would fail occasionally because the user would get logged out when the ajax request was made. (Not really sure why)

To fix the issue avoid a session update on ajax requests.  To do this create a custom session class that overrides the `sess_update` method.

`application/libraries/MY_Session.php`

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session
{
    public function sess_update()
    {
        if (!IS_AJAX) {
            parent::sess_update();
        }
    }
}
```

`IS_AJAX` is defined in `application/config/constants.php`

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

Comment: Where is the IS_AJAX constant coming from? I presumed this was a CI preset but it doesn't seem it is.

Comment: Thanks - I've put in this change just slightly differently, modified the function within the main session library and used the function in the input class (`is_ajax_request`) to check for an AJAX request. Needs to be put to test now - hopefully this will crack it.

Comment: So far so good. Tested after 1hr20mins inactivity and the problem didn't occur. Will give it a few more tests before marking as answer.

Comment: @Stanyer I take it this didn't fix your problem?